# OctoberCMS - Accessing model data in back-end... Returning null?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, octobercms, octobercms-backend

The problem that I'm having is, I cannot access certain information from the File Model such as File Path, File Name, and other information stored in the `system_files` table. I believe I have pinpointed where the issue is coming from, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Below I'll show some of the code.

1) `File.php` ~ File Model

```
<?php namespace Compuflex\Downloads\Models;
use Model;
use October\Rain\Database\Attach\File as FileBase;
/**
 * Model
 */
class File extends FileBase
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;
    /*
     * Validation
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];
    /*
     * Disable timestamps by default.
     * Remove this line if timestamps are defined in the database table.
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'compuflex_downloads_files';
    public $attachOne = [
            'file' => ['System\Models\File', 
                'key' => 'id']
    ];

    public $belongsToMany = [
            'user' => ['RainLab\User\Models\User']
    ];
}
```

In this file, you can see there are two relationships identified: `$attachOne` which attaches the file upload to the File Model as well as `$belongsToMany` which identifies the many-to-many relationship between users and files. (Many files can belong to Many users, or one user can have many files, but one file can also belong to many users). This is the file that sets up the `file` and `user` relation which you will see in the `columns.yaml` file. Just a side note, the only reason I set the `'key'` =>`'id'` was to ensure that it was actually identifying the `'key'` as `'id'`.

2) Columns and Fields

I don't think the `fields.yaml` file is necessary, but just in case, you can find it here:
[fields.yaml](https://github.com/tyamz/compuflex/blob/master/downloads/models/file/fields.yaml)

`columns.yaml`

```
columns:
    file_name:
        label: 'compuflex.downloads::lang.file.name'
        type: text
        searchable: true
        sortable: true
    full_name:
        label: 'compuflex.downloads::lang.file.username'
        type: text
        searchable: true
        sortable: true
        select: name
        relation: user
    email:
        label: 'compuflex.downloads::lang.file.email'
        type: text
        searchable: true
        sortable: true
        select: email
        relation: user
    file:
        label: 'compuflex.downloads::lang.file.path'
        type: text
        searchable: true
        sortable: true
        select: file_name
        relation: file
```

I'm more concerned with the `columns.yaml` file because that is what I am trying to fix is the back-end controller that displays the list of file information as well as information about the users they're "attached" to.

Here is a screenshot of what the view looks like:
[image: Screenshot of Back-end Controller]
As you can see, the "File" Tab is not displaying any information about the file, and it is supposed to be displaying the `file_name` column from the `system_files` table or at least from the File Model, but it displays nothing.

Now, what I find interesting, if I change the last entry in the `columns.yaml` file from the original to:

```
file:
    label: 'compuflex.downloads::lang.file.path'
    type: text
    searchable: true
    sortable: true
```

Then the following is output in the back-end controller:

[image: After the changes...]

Therefore, as you can see, the information **IS** there (*allegedly*), but I'm just not sure how to access it properly.

So, I have one last test that I did that I will show you, I knew that if the `select:` attribute in the `columns.yaml` file is set to a column name that's not in the `system_files` table it *should* produce an SQL Error of some sort (such as column name not found). And I was right... So, I set it to `'ile_name'` instead of `file_name`, just for testing purposes.

Here is what the error message was:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: ile_name (SQL: select "compuflex_downloads_files".*, (select group_concat(name, ', ') 
from "users" inner join "file_user" on "users"."id" = "file_user"."user_id" where "file_user"."file_id" = 
"compuflex_downloads_files"."id") as "full_name", (select group_concat(email, ', ') from "users" inner join "file_user" on "users"."id" = 
"file_user"."user_id" where "file_user"."file_id" = "compuflex_downloads_files"."id") as "email", (select ile_name from "system_files" 
where "system_files"."attachment_id" = "compuflex_downloads_files"."id" and "system_files"."attachment_type" = ? and "field" = ?) as 
"file" from "compuflex_downloads_files" order by "file_name" desc)
```

Now, to pinpoint the issue more, I believe the issue might be coming from:

```
(select ile_name from "system_files" where "system_files"."attachment_id" = "compuflex_downloads_files"."id" and "system_files"."attachment_type" = ? and "field" = ?)
```

I think that those `?` are causing this query to return `NULL` results from the table in turn causing there to be no output. I'm not 100% on this, it's just one possibility. The problem is, I don't know where OctoberCMS builds these queries or if there is any simple way to fix that without touching the actual code for October (for obvious reasons).

***Just a note:*** I apologize if I've included TOO much information here, but I have tried to cut it down. I just wanted to show you that I *DID* try to troubleshoot and solve this myself, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You are too close, you just have to change `type: text` to `type: relation`, also you have to set `nameFrom` attribute:

```
file:
    label: 'compuflex.downloads::lang.file.path'
    type: relation
    searchable: true
    sortable: true
    nameFrom: file_name
    relation: file
```